# Reset Google Apps Admin Password

Tags: google-workspace, password-recovery

I am the sole administrator of my Google Apps account. I cannot remember my password. When I try to reset the password all I am put in is an infinite loop.  I tried [following instructions from Google](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33561) but those put me back into the infinite loop again.

Anyone know how to reset a Google Apps account? I tried phone support but I cannot access phone support without a PIN which is inside my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution after a bit more digging!

If you have a backup email visit this URL:

```
https://admin.google.com/example.com/ForgotAdminAccountInfo
```

Where it has `example.com` in the URL change that to your Google Apps domain. This will give you a captcha to fill out and send instructions on changing your username and/or password.

Another option is to contact Google via a webform. [This page](https://support.google.com/a/contact/admin_no_access) provides this form that you can submit to Google. It does say it can take seven days to process.