# Gmail for Work 'send as' configuration

Tags: google-apps-email

I have an issue that I'm unable to figure out -

I have a Gmail for Work account setup to send from my domain (me@mydomain.com.au) - sends and receives perfectly, MX records setup to point at gmail.

I want to be able to send from the above Gmail for Work account as info@myotherdomain.com.au.

I go into my Gmail for Work account, into settings, accounts, send mail as, follow the prompts though 'add another email address you own' and get this:
[image: Gmail Send As last window]

I'm thinking that the MX records are wrong or something needs to be added/configured on the domain side of things.

Also when I go to [admin.google.com](http://admin.google.com) I can't access any Gmail settings that other forums have hinted at. The below Gmail Settings link takes me straight to my Gmail for Work account:
[image: google admin console]

Do I have to point the MX records at Gmail for Work for this to work? (they are currently pointing to the host's).

Comment: Have take a look to http://support.google.com/a/?

Comment: @Rubén I tried this, I get into a loop trying to verify my domain, however I can't seem to get the google-site-verification number needed

Comment: Then you should solve that first. See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/68995/reset-google-apps-admin-password

Comment: @Rubén thanks for your help you've got me on the right track, turns out the account I was in was just a user account, I now have access to the actual google organisation account so heres hoping this works...

Comment: @Rubén thanks again, with the google org account I had the required access to enable per user gateways in the documentation you provided :)

Comment: Great! Please consider to post an answer with a summary of your findings / what you learned.

Answer (score 1):

The above help in the comments I succeeeded. My issue was that although the account I had was a Google apps account, it was not the administrator account.

I found out who was via Ruben's link above leading to [Google's Forgot Admin Account Info](https://admin.google.com/example.com/ForgotAdminAccountInfo)

After entering my information I could see the domain of the backup address where the admin details had been sent (`havealook.com`) - these were the guys who originally setup the account and had the admin info I was looking for!

Once inside the admin account I was able to

1. Navigate to [admin.google.com](http://admin.google.com)
2. At the bottom under `More Controls` click on `Apps`
3. Once inside apps click on `Google Apps`
4. Once inside `Google Apps` click on `Gmail`
5. Once inside `Gmail` click on `Advanced Settings` at the bottom
6. Scroll down to the `End User Access` section
7. Enable/tick `Allow per-user outbound gateways`

This did not *imediately* work, I had to wait 5ish minutes, after which I was able to log in as my normal gmail user, go to settings/accounts/send as and add my alternate email address, to which the second page asked me for SMTP settings :)